# English translation of the Brahmavaivarta Purana

Tags: translation-request, brahma-vaivarta-purana

Is the complete English translation of the Brahma-vaivarta Purana available for download?
The complete English translation is available at the website
[indianscriptures.com](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/brahmavaivarta-purana)
but is it available for download?
Is some other complete translation available from some other place?

Comment: you can download from there itself

Comment: https://archive.org/details/brahmavaivartapu04allauoft

Comment: @Ajay I know about that translation at archive.org, but it's not complete. Even 4th canto, Krishna janma khanda, is not complete there, it starts with the page 233. I can not download from the indianscriptures.com because there is no a download link there.

Comment: I think you have to do something to download.

Comment: It is available only as individual pdfs and if you want to complete compiled version, it is there in my drive. mail me if you want it.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Did you change your email from .......**r**epository@... to ........**d**epository@...? I remember last time it was ....**r**epository...

Comment: @brahmajijnasa yes. I changed it.

Answer (score 3):

You can find **Brahmavaivarta Purana in Sanskrit text with English translation** in [Archive](https://archive.org/details/357106450BrahmavaivartaPurana2SanskritTextWithEnglishTranslationPdf/page/n1) in two volumes.

These volumes can be downloaded in .pdf format also:

- [Volume 1 pdf](https://archive.org/download/357106450BrahmavaivartaPurana2SanskritTextWithEnglishTranslationPdf/357106438-Brahmavaivarta-Purana-1-Sanskrit-text-with-English-translation-pdf.pdf)
- [Volume 2 pdf](https://archive.org/download/357106450BrahmavaivartaPurana2SanskritTextWithEnglishTranslationPdf/357106450-Brahmavaivarta-Purana-2-Sanskrit-text-with-English-translation-pdf.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay with printed edition, then Parimal Publication has a full translation with original Sanskrit text here:

http://www.parimalpublication.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=4&product_id=83